# c# asp .net Convert to MailAddress

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an application that is going to send an email automatically. I have the preferences(sender,receiver etc...) in web.config file. I am trying for ex to get the receiver like the following

```
          MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmail"];
```

I get the following error. 
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection'. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Try using one of the two constructors that take all-strings - in particular this one that takes 'from' and 'to' email addresses.

```
new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from@from.com", 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmail"])
```

There's also one which accepts a `subject` and `body` (in that order) as additional string parameters as well.

The `To` property is a collection of `MailAddress`es because you can rightly send an email to more than one person.  You cannot, therefore just assign a string to it (it might help to look at the documentation on MSDN?)

You can, however, `Add` a new `MailAddress` or `string` to it. The `MailAddress` constructor has a constructor that simply takes one email string, or one that takes two so you can specify a display name as well.

Answer (score 0):

To is a collection so you can just call `Add` on it...

```
msg.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmail"]);
```

Alternatively you can put them in the constructor as demonstrated by Andras Zoltan with:

```
new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("from@from.com", "to@to.com")
```

But the `Add` method has the advantage that it answers your problems if you want to add to other similar fields (eg `Cc` or `Bcc`).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmail"]);
```

The To property for the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object is of type MailAddressCollection

Answer (score 0):

The new mail settings have different properties. The `To` property is now a MalAddressCollection. You should be able simply to add to it.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmail"]);
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create the MailAddress object. `Add` can take a string which is a comma separated list of addresses.

Comment: @Chris: My habit is to do things explicitly unless there is a need otherwise.

Comment: Fair enough. As long as you know about the overload and are consciously not using it that's fine. I'm not a fan of making things more verbose than they need to be but its just a style preference. :)